# how to install pyaudio 083546

Tags: pyaudio

I got an error while installing pyaudio

I have downloaden portaudio but i am not sure where to put it. I am trying to  create a SpeechRecognition program that won't work without speechrecognition.

The following error occurs:

```
C:\Users\lenovo>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w_ldd4wb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w_ldd4wb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ckrughg6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w_ldd4wb\pyaudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w_ldd4wb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w_ldd4wb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ckrughg6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

edit:
I found a solution for windows!
go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
and then press

`ctrl + f`

to find "pyaudio"
you will get
go and find something like this

`PyAudio: bindings for the PortAudio library. Includes ASIO, DS, WMME, WASAPI, WDMKS support. PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl`

now download the one which is of same version of your python and OS
now after downloading open your cmd/terminal
go to its path and then

`pip install <Pyaudio-blablabla> <= your file name`

now it will be installed!
Enjoy!

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the stacktrace contains the error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

This error can be fixed by installing the suggested tools from:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/